# Nivo Slider effects are not working

Tags: slider, effects, nivo-slider

I've searched and tried several of the solutions to no avail.  I'm currently using jQuery 1.7.1 and Nivo Slider 3.0.1 .

You can see the website at http://www.wheelerbikeclub.net  (this is a website I created last year and I'm just coming back to now).

None of the effects on my nivo slider in my home page are working.  I know there was a point last year where they were, but then I changed something and now they don't and I cannot recollect what it is that happened.

I've made sure the number of columns/boxs/slices evenly divide my images.  Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?  Is it somehow related to the fact that I'm forcing my slider to cover the entire screen?

Thanks for any feedback, I greatly appreciate it!

I make calls for the jQuery followed by NivoSlider script in the head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.3.0.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

Then in my body in a wrapper I put

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default"> 
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="img/new_slides/slide_1-3.png" alt="" title="#slide_1-caption"/>
                <img src="img/new_slides/slide_2-4.png" alt="" />
                <img src="img/new_slides/slide_4.png" alt="" />
                <img src="img/new_slides/slide_3-1.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="slide_1-caption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                <a href="legacy"><strong>Find Out More</strong></a>. 
        </div>
</div>
```

There are four images and I'm just testing the caption with image one.

In my nivo-slider css I have (not the entirety, just where I think the problem might lay)

```
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:2;
}
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }
```

And in my main styles.css I have

```
.slider-wrapper {  position:relative; 
                   top: 0px; 
                   left: 0px; 
                   width: 100%;
                   position:fixed; 
                   z-index:0; }

#slider-div { min-height: 100%;
              height: auto !important;
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0 auto -30px; }
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi. It's a little difficult to understand what exactly you are asking for. Can you give us a brief overview:
a) what you are trying to accomplish b) can you show us the code you tried (here in the question please) and c) what goes wrong (show us a picture or error messages etc)

Comment: a) http://www.wheelerbikeclub.net the images that flash by on this page should have effects similar to how the image fade-in/fade-out or slide or cut-into-slices or into-boxes like on this page http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

b) you can view the code in the page source at http://www.wheelerbikeclub.net it's a static html page, I have tried messing with the z-index of several id's and classes in http://www.wheelerbikeclub.net/css/nivo-slider-new.css according to other posts but it does not fix my problem.

c) There's no error message, it's just I do not see any transition effects

Comment: You seem new here, so I'll explain. the internet comes and goes, but we want S?O to be forever... so we prefer it if you put your code (and errors etc) not in a link to another site - but into your actual question itself. That way, in ten years time when the site link doesn't work anymore - the question here will still make sense and people can still learn from it. :)

Comment: Sorry my fault, I put this in my header to call the jQuery followed by Nivo Slider script and then I load the slider function:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.3.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>`

Comment: I have a similar problem, but for me only the box effects dont work...